# How to base the height of a <p> on whether or not its parent div has an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="eg">
<p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

In the example above, there **is not** an image in the div (.eg) so the css would look like this:

```
.eg p {
height: 10em;
overflow: hidden
}
```

```
<div class="e.g.">
<img src="image.png">
<p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

In the example above, there **is** an image in the div (.eg) so the css would look like this:

```
.eg p {
height: 4em;
overflow: hidden
}
```

How would I achieve this effect?

```
var $Divs = $(".eg");
$Divs.each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).find("img").length > 0) {
            $("p > .eg").css("height", "4em");
      } else {
            $("p > .eg").css("height", "10em", "!important");
      }
});
```

This is my current code though I cannot get it to work

Comment: Why are there periods in `<div class="e.g.">`?

Comment: The selector is the same as the css: `$(".eg p")` or `$(".eg > p")` if the `p` is a first level child.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript is not necessary: use the adjacent (`+`) sibling selector

```
.eg p {
   height: 10em;
   overflow: hidden
}

.eg img + p {
   height: 4em;
}
```

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPVZKa

The last selector will match a paragraph only as immediate sibling element of an image so the `height` will be overrided (for the higher specificity of the rule). The `overflow` property is inherited from previous selector (`.eg p`)

---

Note: if you may have extra elements between image and paragraph use instead the general sibling selector (`~`)

```
.eg img ~ p {
   height: 4em;
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant... O_o

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get this to work, it makes every p have a height of 10em, whether or not its parent div has an image

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPVZKa it works as expected to me. I guess you're trying this solution with a different markup

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/8zxazzgc/ , I've figured out that it does not work if the div has any extra elements (i,e a h2), I forgot to add in the extra '+h2'

Comment: ok, but you should specify this also in your question. see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this too

```js
if($('.eg').children('img').length > 0){
    $('p').css('font-size','10em')
}
```

```css
.eg p {
font-size: 4em;
overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eg">
<img src="image.png">
<p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```